How to deal with the default location of the Ansible CLI tools when creating an Ansible image with Packer
I created an Azure machine image for an Ansible control node using Packer.
I use the shell provisioner to install Ansible from a script as follows:
#!/bin/bash
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt -y install python3-pip
pip3 install ansible
#...

This installs Ansible, but the Ansible CLI tools end up in the /.local/bin dir of the packer user (i.e. under /home/packer/.local/bin). I subsequently deploy the image to Azure using the Terraform azurerm_linux_virtual_machine resource as follows:
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "ansible" {

  # ...

  admin_username  = var.username
  source_image_id = var.source_image_id

  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = var.username
    public_key = var.ssh_public_key
  }

  # ...
}

I'm setting the username variable is set to ryan. When I SSH into this VM as ryan, the Ansible CLI tools are are not under /home/ryan, but rather /home/packer.
How should I deal with this?
Is there a way to get packer to run as a differnet user, or should I add a user in my packer shell provisioner script e.g. sudo adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" ryan, or is there a way to get Ansible to use a differnt location for the CLI tools, or something else?

Full packer template is as follows:
source "azure-arm" "this" {
  client_id                         = var.client_id
  client_secret                     = var.client_secret
  image_publisher                   = var.source_image_publisher
  image_offer                       = var.source_image_offer
  image_sku                         = var.source_image_sku
  location                          = var.location
  managed_image_name                = var.image_name
  managed_image_resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  os_type                           = "Linux"
  subscription_id                   = var.subscription_id
  tenant_id                         = var.tenant_id
  vm_size                           = var.vm_size
}

build {
  sources = ["source.azure-arm.this"]
  provisioner "shell" {
    environment_vars = [
      "PACKER_CONFIG_DIR=/home/${var.username}"
    ]
    script = "./ansible.sh"
  }
}

^^ note: I tried using the PACKER_CONFIG_DIR environment var, but this didn't work...

Can you add the Packer code to the question?

sudo pip3 install ansible. Done. It will install in /usr/local/bin which should be on the path of all users. Installing with pip as root is perfectly acceptable for a docker image.

Is there a reason why you want to install it using pip? Installing tools using package manager is almost always better option. See https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/installation_distros.html#installing-ansible-on-ubuntu or https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/installation_distros.html#installing-ansible-on-debian depending on os type you are using apt in.

This is exclusively Azure, Packer, and Ansible related. Terraform is unrelated here. Packer connects to the Azure instance as the Azure cloudinit-user which is configured to be packer by Packer's AzureRM builder. @Zeitounator comment is best path forward (and probable answer) since packer is the cloudinit-user for the AzureRM builder and therefore would have passwordless sudo permissions, and then the Ansible executable would be globally accessible for execution.
